# How to increase the performance of FlatFileItemReader in SpringBatch?

Tags: performance, batch-processing, spring-batch

I am writing spring batch which reads from flat file, do little processing and write the summary to the output file. My processor and writer are relatively quicker compared to reader. I am using FlatFileItemReader and tried with wide range of commit intervals starting from 50-1000. My batch job has to process 10 millions records on a faster rate. Kindly let me know the ways to improve the speed rate of FlatFileItemReader. pasting below my config file and my Mapper class read the fieldset and set the values to POJO bean. Thanks a lot in advance.

BatchFileConfig.xml

```
<!-- Flat File Item Reader and its dependency configuration starts here -->
<bean id="flatFileReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader">
    <property name="resource" value="classpath:flatfiles/input_10KFile.txt" />
    <property name="encoding" value="UTF-8" />
    <property name="linesToSkip" value="1" />
    <property name="lineMapper">
        <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.DefaultLineMapper">
            <property name="lineTokenizer">
                <bean
                    class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineTokenizer">
                    <property name="names"
                        value="var1,var2,var3,var4,var5,var6" />
                    <property name="delimiter" value="&#009;" />
                    <property name="strict" value="false" />
                </bean>
            </property>
            <property name="fieldSetMapper" ref="companyMapper">
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

CompanyMapper.java

```
 public Company mapFieldSet(FieldSet fieldSet) throws BindException {
    logger.warn("Start time is "+System.currentTimeMillis());
    if (fieldSet != null) {
    Company company = new Company();
    company.setvar1(fieldSet.readString("var1"));
    company.setvar2(fieldSet.readInt("var2"));
    company.setvar3(fieldSet.readString("var3"));
    company.setvar4(fieldSet.readInt("var4"));
    company.setvar5(fieldSet.readInt("var5"));
    company.setvar6(fieldSet.readInt("var6"));
    return company;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Post configuration and some code. Hard to tell, maybe you are doing to much conversion (converting to an object is time-consuming) if you are doing hand-offs this also takes away performance.

Comment: What is your `companyMapper`? Can you post a little more on your job configuration?

Comment: Thanks for your response M. Deinum . Can you see any scope here?

Comment: `System.currentTimeMillis()` is relative slow, wouldn't add that in high-performance code. The same goes for logging, depending on where you log, this could be slow (basically writing to `System.out` is really slow.). The logging also (always) does a `String.concat`. Would try to remove those first and see what happens.

Comment: Also interested in what you think is slow (how long does your procces take). You also might want to attach a profile (JProfiler for instance) to your code and see what is happening inside all those classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can't speed-up process a lot :/
`CompanyMapper` is already a custom implementation so you can think:

1. write a custom `LineTokinizer` + `FieldSet` couple to avoid a lot of (useful) check and error handling
2. write a custom `BufferedReaderFactory` to create your own implementation of `BufferedReader` that wraps a custom (and faster) `InputStream` implementation (look Google for that)

Answer (score 1):

I guess since you are speaking about 10 million data I would suggest you to use spring batchs scaling features. I recently did implementation for posting 5-8 million data to db. To get performance I split the file to say 1 million using File channel( being fast read/write) and then using partitioning I read each file of 1 million in my slave step using a separate thread. Though you might not get good performance difference for small data but to data of this magnitude makes a huge difference. And also as suggested by @M. Deinum try to remove the Logging. It would slow down for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Hello the ultimate way to speed up your reader is to read your file in-memory. Provided that you have enough memory you can read it at once. Provided that you don't you can read as much as you can. Once you have it in memory , you need to implement your "resource" that instead to the physical file will point to the in memory content of your file. Provided that the modern Harddisk speed exceeds 500mg per second even huge file will be read entirely in memory for couple of seconds.

Once it is in memory all your operations will run order of magnitude faster. Also this will provide you with linear capabilities of scaling if you wish so.

If you have your content in memory you can easily paralelise the work without forming bottleneck around your hard disk.